# AppComponent html loading twice at route '/'

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

At route '' (home page) my AppComponent's html is loading twice.

main.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app/components/app/app.component';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app/components/app/app.routing';

if (true) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthComponent } from "../auth/auth.component";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component"

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: AuthComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent
  }
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [provideRouter(appRoutes)];
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl : './app/components/app/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent{

}
```

my index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  {{#unless environment.production}}
  <script src="/ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  {{/unless}}
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <app-component>Loading</app-component>


    {{#each scripts.polyfills}}
    <script src="{{.}}"></script>
    {{/each}}
    <script>
      System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('main');
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

if i remove route '' from routing table html is loading once but i get exception:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''

Comment: Did you tried adding `useAsDefault: true` to `path: ''` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are bootstrapping `AppComponent` and having it as the "default" ('/') path as well. Normally the bootstrapped component contains the "master page" (a constant part of the webpage) while the paths defined in the routes go into the `router outlet`. So if you use a different component for bootstrapping, it should work as you expect.